# Using Cauchy Inequalities to bound coefficients of power series representation

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, cauchy-integral-formula

How do I evaluate the coefficients of a function, that is analytic in the unit disk with a power series $\Sigma a_n z^n$ representation that has the following property 
$$|f'(z)| \leq \frac{1}{1-|z|}$$ in a way such as to see that $|a_n|<e$ for all n.

What I have gotten so far is 
$$|a_n| = \frac{|f^{(n)}(0)|}{n!}\leq\frac{\frac{n!}{R^n}||f||_{\partial D(0,R)}}{n!}\leq\frac{||f||_{\partial D(0,R)}}{R^n}\leq e*||f||_{\partial D(0,1-1/(n+1))} = e * \sup_{|z| = 1-1/(n+1)}f(z),$$ where $R=1-1/n<1.$
But now I should be able to conclude with the help of the assumption that $||f||_{\partial D(0,1-1/n)}<1$, when it would follow that $|a_n|<e$. Can I get some help here?

Comment: why is $||f|<1$ and what is exactly the hypothesis and conclusion? The problem as written is quite confusing as you have a derivative estimate in the OP which is never used; it is definitely not the case that the derivative hypothesis implies that $f$ is bounded

Comment: @Conrad Alright I'll expand on this; but the hypothesis is that a_n < e for all n. Which is why I assumed that the sup over the boundary would be less than one. I might be one the wrong track though.

Comment: @Condrad Is it understandable now?

Comment: ok, now it makes sense - note that $\log(1-z)$ shows that the function is not bounded necessarily; will write the solution though one has to assume $|a_0|<e$ since the derivative relation allows any $a_0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We apply the Cauchy relation for $g(z)=f'(z)=\sum {b_nz^n}$ and get that:

$|b_n| \le \frac{\sup_{|z|=R}{|g(z)|}}{R^n} \le \frac{1}{(1-R)R^n}$. But with $R_n=1-\frac{1}{n+1}, n \ge 1$, $R_n^n > \frac{1}{e}, 1-R=\frac{1}{n+1}$, so $|b_n| < (n+1)e, n \ge 1$, while $|b_0| \le 1 <e$. But we have $b_n=(n+1)a_{n+1}, n \ge 0$ hence $|a_n| < e, n \ge 1$.

Note that the derivative inequality cannot determine $a_0$ as $f+c$ satisfies same for arbitrary $c$, so we must assume $|a_0| <e$ for completion

Comment: Ah thank you so much, that makes complete sense!

Comment: Happy to be of help - you had the right idea, just needed to apply it to the derivative as you had estimate for it not for function

Comment: Yes quite, my previous exercise was precisely to limit a_n<(n+1)e when the assumption held for |f(x)| but I didn't see that you could just calculate the coefficients of the derivative, although obvious in hindsight. Was just fixated on making the evaluation more precise.